# My dropdown nav menus do not stay down. Cannot click to the subpages

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a site in development at: http://www.spark-creative.ca/ftt/index.php

On the homepage, in all browsers, the top nav bar works, but there are 3 sections with dropdown submenus - About Us, Training, and Careers. These dropdown subnavs should stay down until a user clicks on a subpage, but they disappear once I mouse off the main top nav.

This worked fine for a while, but has stopped working recently during recent construction, and not sure why.

The inside pages of the site do not have this issue, and work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a gap between menu list and menu item that breaks the hover. Either delete the `<div class="top_shadow_home"></div>` inside `middle_content_holder` inside `container_full` or remove the gap from css.

[image: pic]

It looks like `top_shadow_home` is breaking the hover. When it is removed it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you @user568109 ! That is where the answer was. One tweak and it is working perfectly :)